# Sum score between an effective time range in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sum, date-range

I have the following sample data in a SQL Server database.

```
UserID Score StartDate   EndDate
------------------------------------
1      10    2019-06-01  2019-07-15
1      20    2019-06-20  2019-07-01
1      30    2019-06-17  2019-07-25
2      10    2019-05-15  2019-06-10
2      20    2019-06-15  2019-07-01
2      30    2019-06-20  2019-07-15
```

And I need to achieve the following result.

```
UserID ScoreTotal StartDate   EndDate
----------------------------------------
1      10         2019-06-01  2019-06-17
1      40         2019-06-17  2019-06-20
1      60         2019-06-20  2019-07-01
1      40         2019-07-01  2019-07-15
1      30         2019-07-15  2019-07-25
2      10         2019-05-15  2019-06-10
2      20         2019-06-15  2019-06-20
2      50         2019-06-20  2019-07-01
2      30         2019-07-01  2019-07-15
```

It doesn't matter whether the score of the `startdate` or `enddate` is included in each calculation.

Any help would be the most appreciated.

Comment: If you could provide the logic for your output too, that will be helpful

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your relation is `A`, the following query performs the operation you need:

```
WITH unwrapped AS (
    SELECT UserID, SUM(Score) AS Score, StartDate AS TempDate
    FROM A
    GROUP BY UserID, StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserID, SUM(-1*Score) AS Score, EndDate AS TempDate
    FROM A
    GROUP BY UserID, EndDate
)
SELECT uw1.UserID, SUM(uw1.Score) AS ScoreTotal, MAX(uw1.TempDate) AS StartDate, uw2.TempDate AS EndDate
FROM unwrapped uw1 INNER JOIN unwrapped uw2
     ON uw1.UserID = uw2.UserID AND uw1.TempDate < uw2.TempDate
GROUP BY uw1.UserID, uw2.TempDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to accumulate the scores by periods where the score is constant.  This is a bit tricky because it might require date arithmetic which varies by database.  The idea is to unpivot the values and use aggregation and window functions:

```
with tt as (
      select userid, score, startdate as dte
      from t
      union all
      select userid, -score, enddate as dte
      from t
     ) t
select userid, sum(sum(score)) over (partition by userid order by (dte)) as score,
       dte, lead(dte) over (partition by userid order by dte)
from tt
group by userid, dte
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I added 'PARTITION BY userID' for the first window function and then it will return the correct result.

Comment: @SeanXu . . . I fixed the answer.  This should have *much* better performance than a self-join answer.